# OpenVPN server throws an "access denied" error

Tags: openvpn, keys

OpenVPN refuses to start up and exists with this error ever since i upgraded Ubuntu from 1.04 to 11.10

```
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: OpenVPN 2.2.0 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Jul  4 2011
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: Note: cannot open openvpn-status.log for WRITE
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: Note: cannot open ipp.txt for READ/WRITE
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: Cannot load private key file server.key: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: Error: private key password verification failed
Dec 14 19:12:38 oogle ovpn-server[32150]: Exiting
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: OpenVPN 2.2.0 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Jul  4 2011
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: Note: cannot open openvpn-status.log for WRITE
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: Note: cannot open ipp.txt for READ/WRITE
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: Cannot load private key file server.key: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: Error: private key password verification failed
Dec 14 19:12:46 oogle ovpn-server[32201]: Exiting
```

Comment: What user is trying to start the openvpn server? What are the permission set to on the folder holding the private keys?

Comment: @Alex See my answer, strange stuff

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strangely, starting OpenVPN using the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

causes this error while starting it using

```
service openvpn start
```

does not thrown up any error!

Comment: This makes no sense at all. OpenVPN has no separate Upstart init-file, so both commands just invoke the old-style SysVinit init.d-style initscript.

Comment: You are issuing the `service` command with sudo or from `root` directly (`sudo su`)? I think this can be the explanation because your problem is with permissions on the openvpn config/log files.

Comment: Oh god I did a stupid thing I did not add sudo to `/etc/init.d/openvpn start`, that's why it did not start ~_~

Comment: haaa looks better :) This is why openvpn can't open the files.

Answer (score 2):

Answering on behalf of OP from comments

I did not add `sudo` to `/etc/init.d/openvpn start`, that's why it did not start

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permissions for the user openvpn runs to be able to read/write the log files, to read the ssl keys/certs files and to `rw` `/etc/openvpn/ipp.txt` (this file controls who will get which IP).

From what I understood in your answer, when you start it as root (not sudo) it works.

Obs: if your permissions looks ok, maybe it's apparmor denying access to the files.

Edit:
 You have `Error: private key password verification failed` in your log. Your private key needs a password? If so, you won't be able to start it automatically.